# How to rename a file with the top folder name when files are in subdirectories in powershell

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0

Here is my problem.
I have files in subdirectories and I need the file renamed as such:

```
{TOP DIRECTORY}_{SECOND DIRECTORY}_{FILENAME.ext}
```

The folder structure is like such:

```
AB12345
  EVENT1
    report.xls
  EVENT2
    SUBFOLDER
      report2.xls
  EVENT3
    SUBFOLDER
      SUBFOLDER2
        report3.xls
```

With the expected results below.  We do not care about the folders up under the second level, if present.

```
AB12345_EVENT1_report.xls
AB12345_EVENT2_report2.xls
AB12345_EVENT3_report3.xls
```

I have this base code that I have started:

```
Get-ChildItem C:\Files -Recurse | Rename-Item -NewName { $_.Directory.name+'_'+$_.Name}
```

Comment: What is missing from your current code? Or, what is failing? Or, where do you need help?

Comment: the current listed code, only give me the directory right before it sees the file and what I need is the FIRST two directories and the file name.

Comment: Where do you want the files to end up? Should they remain in the directories they're in now or be brought back to `C:\Files`

Answer (score 0):

Because you're doing something with renaming multiple files, I would suggest that you use the `-WhatIf` switch in the following code and check the output before running it - once you're happy with what the command is going to do, take the `-WhatIf` off:

- Firstly, you only want to rename files, so you need to get your `Get-ChildItem` to do that - the `-File` switch will do that for you
- You can use `Select-Object` to build the new file name for you. `Select-Object` can simply pick members of the object by name, however it can also take a hash-table as an argument. We provide a hash-table that contain a member name "NewName" which is defined by the following Expression
- `$_.FullName | Resolve-Path -Relative` - this part gets the fullpath for the file but relative to the current location. It returns values such as:

```
.\AB12345\EVENT1\report.xls
.\AB12345\EVENT2\SUBFOLDER\report2.xls
```

- Now we use `-split` with `'\\'` (double-backslash is required as an escape for a single backslash which is a special character when using split)
- The split returns this:

```
{., AB12345, EVENT1, report.xls}
{., AB12345, EVENT2, SUBFOLDER...}
{., AB12345, EVENT3, SUBFOLDER...}
```

- Nearly there, we just need the 2nd and 3rd elements as our new filename (the first and second directory names), use [1..2] to get these elements out and then add on the filename. Finally join these by underscore to get the new filename.
- Pass the new filename along with the full path to `rename-item`, using `-WhatIf` to review what the command will do:

```
Get-ChildItem -Recurse -File | `
Select-Object `
@{ `
  Name="NewName"; `
  Expression={$($($_.FullName | Resolve-Path -Relative) -split '\\')[1..2]+$_.Name -join '_'}; `
} `
,FullName | `
%{ `
  rename-item $_.FullName -NewName $_.NewName -Whatif `
}
```

N.B. backticks have been used to display the command in a more readable manner